# Reading lines of a txt file as floats in C

Tags: c, file-io

I have a text file with text that goes like this:

```
p 1.002 2.705 3.601
p 4.005 9.001 1.044
...
```

I want to get the float values and assign them to variable. So far I've got

```
FILE *fileStream = fopen("file.txt, "r");
char fileText[100];
float x;
while (fgets(fileText, sizeof fileText, fileStream))
    {
        if (fileText[0] == 'p')
        {
            x = fileText[2];
            printf("%f",x);
        }
    }
    fclose(fileStream);
```

But it's printing out some float that isn't on the line. I am new to C, so I'm not sure how to go about getting the floats. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not use `fgets` followed by `sscanf`?

Comment: `float x, y, z;` then after `fgets()`, `if (sscanf (fileText, "p %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z) != 3) { /* handle error */ }` Otherwize, `x`, `y`, `z` now hold the 3-floats from that line.

Comment: @kiranBiradar (I think you meant `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, Thank you :D

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read floating-point numbers from a **txt** file, maybe you should use `fscanf` function to read every value you want from a file.

In my opinion, you should use following instruction to read a floating-point number by your text file you provided:

`fscanf(fileStream, "p %f", &x);`

By the function above, `p` is read and ignored but the first floating-point number is read and put in the variable `x` and you can print it by `printf("%f", x);`.

You can also read more about it in [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm).

Second, You're going to get a compile-time error by this instruction you entered in your code:

`x = fileText[2];`

That's because you can't initialize a couple of characters to a floating-point number. It's meaningless. To convert a string into a floating-point number, you should use this function to convert a string into a floating-point number:

`x = atof(fileText);`

by the function above, if your program was able, it's converted `fileText` into a floating-point number and put it in `x` variable.

You should include `stdlib.h` to use `atof()`.